# adding new module in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, module

I'm sorry if my question is not good quality.I have problem when I want to understanding wordpress , I'm new in wordpress, and I want to create some module in wordpress, It's Possible?

ex.

1. if i want to add module, what must I'm studying in wordpress ?

Comment: Module ? You mean `widget` or `plugin` ? I think you should post your question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: @viyancs Check this, i think it will help u to understand the anatomy http://en.support.wordpress.com/modules/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joomla usually refers to a module.  Writing one in WordPress is considered a plugin.  You should start studying the Codex and it will lay what you need to do out for you.

You can find that on the WordPress site at [Writing_a_Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)

> WordPress Plugin: A WordPress Plugin is a program, or a set of one or more functions, written in the PHP scripting language, that adds a specific set of features or services to the WordPress weblog, which can be seamlessly integrated with the weblog using access points and methods provided by the WordPress Plugin Application Program Interface (API).
>
> Wishing that WordPress had some new or modified functionality? The first thing to do is to search various WordPress Plugin repositories and sources to see if someone has already created a WordPress Plugin that suits your needs. If not, this article will guide you through the process of creating your own WordPress Plugins.

Comment: so with plugin we can modify anymore in wordpress....?

maybe i will study how to create plugin in wordpress so i can add new plugin like i want..:) right?

Comment: You use plugins in WordPress to add new functionality to WordPress.  The question is quite vague.  If you need more details or examples please let me know.  If you are looking for functionality in Wordpress you can try searching the existing plugins and installing a few.  The plugin directory is at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

Comment: example in here i want adding cart function in wordpress should I create plugin for that?

Comment: If you want a cart in WordPress there are plenty of options that provide solutions for many features and payment gateways.  I have used several of them.  Search that plugin directory and you can find many.  There are several cart options you can find via google.  If I answered your question, please mark it as answered.  Thanks.

Comment: yeah that is just example,  I mean if i want to create similiar cart  function , I must create plugin for custom wordpress or not? or any anohter way ?

Comment: Yes, sure, write a plugin.  Many carts are fully customizable but many of the great ones are not free.  If you are comfortable, get coding.  I hope I answered your question.  You asked me until I agreed with you.  LOL.

Answer (score 0):

To develop WP plugins, you must familiar with wordpress hooks and API functions.

You can start learning/exploring from any existing plugins. I had started with "Hello_Dolly" :)